# Want to add element. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/w5nAr/5/) JSfiddle have I a checkbox, a label and a submit button.

When the checkbox is checked, and submit is clicked a 'x' should appear, like to does now.

When the checkbox is unchecked, and submit is clicked a 'x' should disappear, like to does now.

The problem is that the 'x' doesn't appear again, if the checkbox is checked, and submit is clicked.

This is my code

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    if( $("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')){
        $("label").add();
    }else{   
        $("label").detach();
    }        
    return false;
});


<form action="" method="post">
<input id="element" signed" type="checkbox" checked>
<label for="element">x</label>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: `<input id="element" signed" type="checkbox" checked>` contains a quote mark mismatch.

Comment: You could give it an ID on the label and show / hide it based on that? and as Tom said your syntax error causing probs too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you use `show()` and `hide()` instead of `add()` and `detach()`, it works.

But I'm not certain if that approach addresses what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

When you `detach` the label, it's no longer in the DOM, so `$('label')` no longer works. You'll have to store the node somewhere whilst it's not in the DOM.

Also `add` is not the correct function to add a node into the DOM.

```
var $label = $("label");
$('form').submit(function() {
    if( $("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')){
        $("input[type=checkbox]").after($label);
    }
    else {   
        $label.detach();
    }        
    return false;
});
```

[Here's a live example.](http://jsfiddle.net/AD3XL/)

Answer (score 1):

The `x` doesn't appear again because you are not adding the detached element, you are *trying* to add a new element without a text.

```
$("label").add();
```

See the correct use of [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).

Also, you are detaching and not saving the reference to attach it back. See [an example of detach on jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)

Answer (score 1):

After detaching the label is no longer part of the DOM, so you can no longer select it using `$('label')`, also [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) doesnt do what you think it does, you might be looking for [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)?

[Working fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/w5nAr/6/)

```
xLabel = $("label");
$('form').submit(function() {
    if( $("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')){
        $("#element").after(xLabel);
    }else{   
        $("label").detach();
    }        
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I doubt she's looking for `append`.

Comment: @Kirstoffer: Not really, as evidenced by the fact that your example uses `after`. :)

Comment: ...right, no more coffee for me... `append` is out the window