# Sorting column with check boxes. Doesn't work. I am stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like that the Signed button in this JSfiddle sorts the column with the check boxes, like it actually does perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/DSRmg/

I noticed that `tinySort`, the library used to sort the tables, can't sort the column with just the check boxes, so I added a `&nbsp;` (or X in the JSfiddle for visability) for those `<td>`'s that have the check box checked, and it could sort the column.

**Problem**

The problem is, that when Save is clicked the `&nbsp;` or X in this case, should be added, so when Signed is clicked, the column is sorted correctly.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343524/want-to-add-element-whats-wrong) post learned I how to add and remove `&nbsp` or X.

It seams to me that JQuery can't find the `<label>`, because it is inside a `<td>`.

**How to reproduce problem**

Try un-checking one of the checkboxes and click Signed. Now the check box column is not sorted correctly any longer.

**Question**

How do I get the Save buttons to add a `&nbsp;`, so the column can be sorted?

**Update**

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/DSRmg/4) have I implemented Rakesh's answer of tablesort. But I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Looks like its working for me. I am able to sort the columns.

Comment: yes, you can sort yhe columns just fine. But, try unchecking one of the checkboxes, and then sort again. now it is not sorted correctly anymore =(

Comment: Doesn't look like there is an event listener to remove the x's when a user clicks the checkboxes, you will have to add one to make the sort work.

Comment: @Nick Pyett : I hope I have fixed this in this jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/DSRmg/4 which is based on Rakesh's answer. But it still doesn't do anything =( Can you see what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/) plugin which gives you an option to have your own parser logic for sorting.

Take a look at the code - http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/DSRmg/8/

HTML:

```
<td class="checkbox"> <input name="signed" type="checkbox" checked ><span class="hidden">1</span> </td>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myTable").tablesorter();              
    $('#myTable input:checkbox').click(function() {
        var order = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
        $(this).next().html(order);
        $(this).parents("table").trigger("update");
    })
});
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this, but I keep getting the error `not well formed`. Here is the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/DSRmg/2/ . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/littlesandra88/DSRmg/4/ Same problem however.

Comment: @Sandra Please see the updated version of the code - http://jsfiddle.net/srakesh/DSRmg/8/

Answer (score 0):

missing a semi colon:

```
$('#myTable input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var order = this.checked ? '1' : '0';
    $(this).next().html(order);
    $(this).parents("table").trigger("update");
}); //try putting a semicolon here
```